# Do C# and java does support static types?

Tags: c#, java

I have been using Singleton classes and static method for a while and always used to wonder how nice it would have been to have a seperate type which is a static type and cannot be instantiated but have only static methods!

It will be easy for readability and also to maintain.

for Ex

```
public UtilType MyUtility
{
  public void Calculate(int x,int y)
  {
    return x+y;
  }
}
```

Here `MyUtility` should not be allowed to be instantiated only its methods can be accessed in static way.

Comment: Don't rely on singletons! They are only unique within a class loader and of course a single jvm.

Comment: @CurtainDog: For a utility class that is just a collection of static methods with no state that does not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why C# and java does not support util type ?

To answer your question, we cannot read the minds of the designers of C# and Java, so we can only infer their reasons for not supporting 'utility' classes.  But the reasons probably include:

- Utility classes are not object oriented, and are infrequently used in well designed OO application.
- They are semantically redundant.  You can code a normal class so that it cannot be instantiated, which is the only essentially different thing about a utility class.
- The coding effort to turn a regular class into a "utility" class is trivial.  In Java for example it is one line of code; i.e. a private no-arg constructor.

Since utility classes are semantically redundant, infrequently used, and trivial to code in Java / C# as they are currently specified, there is no real case to add syntactic sugar to the language to support them.

And even if it were a good idea, the down-sides of making such a change would include:

- The considerable cost of revising language specifications, modifying compilers and associated tools, revising / extending tutorials and text books, and so on.
- The impact on the existing Java / C# customer application codebase of adding a new keyword.
- The extra increment of difficulty in learning the language caused by adding a new class variant.

Answer (score 9):

In C# you can do that by using the `static` keyword:

```
public static class MyUtility
{
    public static void Calculate(int x,int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

That would allow you to write

```
var result = MyUtility.Calculate(1, 2);
```

all over your code.

However, it is not very object-oriented, so always consider if there are better alternatives. Object-oriented design is about **data and behavior**, and such a static class is pure behavior. That's almost as bad as classes that are pure data, but those are often seen together.

I personally find overuse of static types a **code smell**.

Comment: I disagree to this.
wont you often have a piece of code which does just pure calculation without changing non static object values?
There is always need for static methods.Or atleast i have found so many times

Comment: Do you also find all of LINQ to be a code smell? What about purely functional languages?

Comment: @Ravisha: Notice that I wrote that *overuse* of static types is a code smell. Pure calculation is one exception, but they are actually rarer than one may think (and are often already implemented by the BCL). If you pass two or more complex types to a static method, chances are that the method would have been more appropriate on one of those types.

Comment: @Justice: No, I don't find LINQ to be a code smell, but in a larger perspective they may actually be, because they act as a substitute for mixins. When it comes to functional languages it's a different discussion - `static` is a code smell in OOD. The concept of static (or shared) state is more or less meaningless in FP because everything is immutable in the first place - there is no state.

Comment: @Mark I have mentioned that its about pure calculation which is required for methods to be made as static.I dont think in good design anyone would make object changes in a static method so code smell doesn seem relevent here

Comment: Remember that the term *code smell* denotes that a particular piece of code warrants further investigation. The code may be turn out to be fine after all, but on average, it's not. Pure calculation often turns out to be the exception that proves the rule, but personally, I *very* rarely need to implement classes that implement pure calculation because my class libraries already provide what I need. Granted, if you work with advanced mathematics, your situation may be entirely different than mine, in which case static classes may be warranted.

Comment: @Mark Partly agreed :):)
I would say pure non state processing rather than calcualtion.
Since based on parameter passed there will be processing of instructions to yeild particular result.Which i have come across a lot:)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried... static types?

```
public static class MyUtility
{
    public static void Calculate(int x,int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class AnyOtherClass
{
     public void AnyOtherMethod()
     {
          MyUtility.Calculate(4,5);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refining the answer posted by `masher`

```
public final class Utilities
{
 // private constructor
 private Utilities(){ }

 public static int add(int x, int y)
 {
  return x+y;
 }

 public static int subtract(int x, int y)
 {
  return x-y;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't this work? (in Java)

```
public class Utilities
{
   private Utilities() {} //added in an edit after reading comments

   public static int add(int x, int y)
   {
      return x+y;
   }

   public static int subtract(int x, int y)
   {
      return x-y;
   }
}
```

(Now) You can't instantiate it, it only has static methods...

Comment: Actually, you CAN instantiate it using the default constructor.  The normal way to prevent instantiation is to declare a private constructor with no arguments.

Comment: `Why doesn't this work?` i guess it will work.  Alongwith above code, try having a private constructor as well.

Comment: Well, you can instantiate it (because of the default constructor). But I don't see why that would be a problem anyway.

Comment: @Stephen: http://lh3.ggpht.com/_2VEaTPMR9yw/So75itBGUSI/AAAAAAAAAUQ/5c2iup4N3EM/funny_cow_picture_moo%5B2%5D.jpg

Comment: @Rakesh It was more of a rhetorical question. I assumed that the OP had already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring a private constructor?

```
public class MyUtility
{
    private MyUtility ( )
    {
    }

    public static int calculate(int x,int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

With Java 5+, you can even use static import.

```
...
import static MyUtility.calculate

...
void myMethod ( )
{
  int sum = calculate( 1, 2 );
}
```

Comment: I agree it is possible.My question is about having a new type.
I am not ruling out of possibility of acheiving this with existing ways

Comment: Using a private constructor is essentially the same thing as declaring the class static in C# 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a private constructor you can use an enum type (which has a private constructor by default.

```
public enum Utilities {
   ; 

   public static int add(int x, int y) { 
      return x+y; 
   } 

   public static int subtract(int x, int y) { 
      return x-y; 
   } 
}
```

Note: you need a lone semi-colon to indicate there are are no values of the enum.

Comment: @Peter Is this better than class with private constructor(Except for default constructor)

Answer (score -1):

I think an answer to the original question is that both languages are Object-oriented by definition. So, objects are first-class citizens i.e. everything is an object.

That's how the language was designed, how it's intended to be used and how the compiler figures out how to link parts of code to create a program.

`static` helps make our lives easier, but sometimes we have to pay for that. for example, when you wish you could override a static method.

Comment: how does this explanation link to the question.This seems more like a generic opinion

Comment: The original question was something like: Why doesn't Java/C# support utility methods? Methods defined outside classes and called statically. It was edited later.

Comment: rolled back the question tag.Thnks for informing

Comment: @ahmadabdolkader But still i am talking about having a seperate type (a new type which is neither static nor instantiable)

Comment: I see. I thought you were looking for an answer to your question. I guess this is more like a new feature request.

Comment: an argument for the down vote? at least this is similar to the selected answer.